# Is there a unique solution to the cauchy problem $y'=f(t,y)$ for $f\in \mathcal C^1(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R)$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f\in \mathcal C^1(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R)$ and consider $$\begin{cases}y'=f(t,y)\\ y(0)=0.\end{cases}$$

This equation has :

1) A local solution but not necessarily unique

2) A unique global solution

3) We don't have enough information to conclude

4) Has not necessarily a global solution.

**Attempt**

I would say that $f'$ is bounded on each interval $[k,k+1]$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$, and thus, by a theorem, the equation has a unique solution on all those interval. Let write $y_k$ this solution. Let $y(x)=y_k(x)$ for all $x\in [k,k+1]$ for all $k$. Then, if I can show that $y$ is $\mathcal C^1$, it's a solution. But it is since on $[k-\frac{1}{2},k+\frac{1}{2}]$ there is a unique solution $u_k$ that is $\mathcal C^1$ and by unicity, $u_k=y_{k-1}$ on $[k-\frac{1}{2},k]$ and $u_k=y_k$ on $[k,k+\frac{1}{2}]$.

But my teacher says that it doesn't work, and I don't understand why. So what is the correct solution ?

Comment: "by a theorem", which one ? Plus, try solving $y'=y^2$ and $y(0)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would say that $f′$ is bounded on each interval $[k,k+1]$ for $k∈Z$,
>   and thus, by a theorem, the equation has a unique solution on all
>   those interval

This is wrong. The classical counterexample is
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
y'= y^2\\
y(0)=2
\end{array}\right.
$$
Here $y^2\in \mathcal C^{\infty}$ and bounded on $[0;1]$, but the solution does not exist on $[0;1]$:
$$
\frac{dy}{y^2}=dt
$$
$$
y=\frac1{C-t}
$$
$$
y=\frac1{\frac12-t}
$$
It tends to infinity at $t\to \frac12$